# Лучший способ инициализировать поля класа. move vs const &

Tags: c++, c++11, best-practice

Есть класс с некоторым копируемым полем.

```
class Foo{
    Bar _bar;
    //...
};
```

До появления move семантики, я бы сказал что лучший способ инициализировать `_bar` это передать константую ссылку на него:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : 
    _bar(bar)
{}
```

Но, чтобы сделать нашу жизнь <strike>сложнее</strike> лучше, появилась move семантика. И у меня возник вопрос. А какой теперь лучший способ инициализировать поля класса? Грубо говоря все сводится к:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : 
    _bar(bar)
{}
```

vs.

```
Foo::Foo(Bar bar) : 
    _bar(std::move(bar))
{}
```

Очевидно что в некоторых ситуациях лучше один конструктор, а в некоторых другой. Может есть какое-нибудь "правило большого палца" или best practice на эту тему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от того, есть у Bar конструктор перемещения или нет.

Если его нет - то константная ссылка будет лучшим решением:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : _bar(bar) {}
```

Если он есть - то лучше использовать временный объект, лишние перемещения заинлайнятся на этапе оптимизации:

```
Foo::Foo(Bar bar) : _bar(std::move(bar)) {}
```

Если вы не знаете если он или его нет - можно попробовать вот такой вариант:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : _bar(bar) {}
Foo::Foo(Bar &&bar) : _bar(std::move(bar)) {}
```

Comment: А во втором случае не окажется копирование с перемешением, в то время как в первом это будет просто копирование (как сказано у @Harry)?

Comment: @Mikhailo во втором случае будет выбран наилучший способ из доступных. Либо копирование с перемещением (которое один фиг оптимизируется), либо два перемещения (которые тоже оптимизируются).

Comment: Т.е. вы просто полагаетесь на оптимизацию?

Comment: @Mikhailo в этом вся современная разработка на плюсах

Answer (score 2):

Гм... мне кажется, что лучше `Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar)` и `Foo::Foo(Bar&& bar)`.

Ваш вариант с `Foo::Foo(Bar bar)` окажется не лучшим, если `Bar` не умеет перемещаться - будут просто лишние копирования.

Comment: Для одного аргумента - да. Но в общем случае нужно писать 2^число_аргументов перегрузок.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Но нас-то и спрашивают об одном варианте :)

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас есть "детальный" вариант реализации с двумя конструкторами

   ```
   Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : _bar(bar) {}
   Foo::Foo(Bar &&bar) : _bar(std::move(bar)) {}
   ```

   отдельно для копирования и отдельно для перемещения.
2. "Ленивый" вариант реализации с одним конструктором

   ```
   Foo::Foo(Bar bar) : _bar(std::move(bar)) {}
   ```

   который покрывает функциональность первых двух с незначительной потерей эффективности.
3. И forwarding вариант реализации с прямой конструкцией `_bar` на месте, без создания промежуточного `Bar`

   ```
   template<typename... Args>
   Foo::Foo(Args&&... args) : _bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
   ```